# How to change google time from EST to IST?

Tags: google-search, time-zone

When I search something time related in Google like *"when will X telecast"*,*"X vs Y"* like this, the result shows for **EST** time. I'm in **IST** timezone and would like to get the result accordingly. My friend get the result in IST but he doesn't know how he gets that. So I'm asking here. Picture for more illustration

[image]

I want this *All times are in Eastern Time* -> *All times are in Indian Standard Time*

PS : I tried changing time zone from Google Calendar, but same thing is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching from the [indian google site](https://www.google.co.in/) does the trick. Searching [fifa 2014](https://www.google.co.in/#q=fifa+2014) gives

[image]